# Different action on several DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I currently have a form in which there is 2 datePicker (Jquery UI).
On the first one, when I "mouseenter" a date, I do an AJAX call to get a response (and it works).
The problem here is that the AJAX call works for both the datePicker. I want it for the first one only!
Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Next relaunch</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id ="nextLaunchDate">
        <input name="nextLaunchDate" class="datePicker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="Next relaunch">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Validity date</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input name="validityDate" class="datePicker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="Validity date">
    </div>
</div>
```

In fact, it's quite basic. Now, here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            showWeek: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });

    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".ui-state-default", function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var day = (0 + "" + $(this).text()).slice(-2);
        var month = $(this).parent().attr("data-month");
        month++;
        month = (0 + "" + month).slice(-2);
        var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + element.parent().attr("data-year");

        $(this).attr('title', date);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/offer/getrelaunchthatday',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'dateSelected=' + day + "-" + month + "-" + element.parent().attr("data-year"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json_response) {
                if (json_response.status === "success") {
                    element.attr('title', "Offers today : "+json_response.value);
                }
                else {
                    $(".x_panel:first").before("<div class=\"alert alert-danger deletable\">An error happened : <br/>" + json_response.value + "</div>");
                }
            },
            error: function (result, status, error) {
                $(".x_panel:first").before("<div class=\"alert alert-danger deletable\">An error happened: <br/>" + error+ "</div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I understand why the ajax call works for both of the datePicker but I can't understand how I can do the call only for the second one.
If you have any idea about this, don't hesitate to comment! Also, if you have any note on my code, tell me! :)
Have a good day!

EDIT : Here's a codePen to show you my problem : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLmpbN

Comment: Where is `.ui-state-default` class?

Comment: It's the one generated by the jquery UI datePicker, added just before the closing </body>

Comment: Can't you use `ids` to add event listeners seperately

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so : the two input use the same datepicker, it's not related to the input. Try it by yourself! :) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLmpbN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `jQuery` use same date picker component for both inputs, you should add conditional checks using `ids`. See the following example where two date pickers have different actions when `mouseover`.

```js
var datePicker = "";

//First date picker
$("#first_date").datepicker({
  beforeShow: function() {
    datePicker = "FIRST_DATE";
  },
  onClose: function() {
    datePicker = "";
  }
});

//Second date picker
$("#second_date").datepicker({
  beforeShow: function() {
    datePicker = "SECOND_DATE";
  },
  onClose: function() {
    datePicker = "";
  }
});

//Add conditional mouse hover events

$("body").on("mouseenter", ".ui-state-default", function() {
  if (datePicker == "FIRST_DATE") {
    //Do first date picker stuff
    console.log("on first date picker");
  } else {
    //Do second date picker stuff
    console.log("on second date picker");
  }


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>First Date:
    <input type="text" id="first_date">
  </p>

  <p>Second Date:
    <input type="text" id="second_date">
  </p>


</body>

</html>
```

You should use `ids` rather than using a class name for different date inputs.

Comment: I used boolean instead of string but it's excellent, thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help you. Strings will suit for more than two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Just umm... 
There is no answer. 
It is just your choice. ! :)

```
<input type="text" id="first_date" class="datePicker" data-type="test1">
<input type="text" id="second_date" class="datePicker" data-type="test2">

$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

$("body").on("mouseenter", ".datePicker", function(e) {
    var type = $(this).data('type');

    if (type == 'test1') {

    } else {
        // test2
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a great idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the event through the class name.

HTML

```
<div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Next relaunch</label>
        <input name="nextLaunchDate" class="datePicker form-control col-md-7" title="Next relaunch">
</div>
<div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Validity date</label>
         <input name="validityDate" class="datePicker2 form-control col-md-7" title="Validity date">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

$(".datePicker2").datepicker({
    showWeek: false,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Otherwise, you can assign an event based on the class name through JQuery.

good day~

Comment: These different classes are not available under the date picker ui since it is positioned `absolute` with the `body`. Therefore `mouseover` events can not be added using these two classes.

Answer (score -1):

You missed "<" in second label. And use current input in your function, not "body"

Comment: You should provide an example on how to achieve the desired result without just telling the issue.

Comment: You're right but it's because it was a french label, I translated it and removed the "<" by error, it's not related to my problem :)